# Changing existing NAT rule on Cisco ASA

Tags: networking, firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

This is the exact line I want to edit

```
nat (inside,outside) source static thatplace thatplace destination static thisplace thisplace no-proxy-arp route-lookup
```

All I want to do is enable `proxy-arp`. 
How can I do that?

Comment: "_All I want to do is enable proxy arp._" No, you do not want to enable proxy ARP. That is a security hole, and you should not do that. Properly configured routing will not require proxy ARP.

Answer (score 0):

*Ignoring* whether the desired proxy-arp change is appropriate for the environment (nods to @ron-maupin), the way to accomplish the stated objective from ASA CLI is to "no out" the command, then re-enter with the option removed.

```
no nat (inside,outside) source static thatplace thatplace destination static thisplace thisplace no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (inside,outside) source static thatplace thatplace destination static thisplace thisplace route-lookup
```

The CLI parameter is `no-proxy-arp`. There is *not* a `proxy-arp` parameter. Absence of the `no-proxy-arp` parameter enables proxy-arp on the NAT rule.

After making `nat` changes the ASA's `xlate` table (`show xlate`) will keep previous xlate entries in the xlate table in place until the associated conn ends (at which point the xlate timeout kicks in. `clear xlate` will forcefully clear the xlate table (`clear xlate` is intrusive, only perform during maintenance window).